# Invalid Selector sent to instance - objectForKey:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I get an error when running my code.  The culprit is me accessing a string from a plist below:

```
    NSString *sImageFile = [dictionary objectForKey:@"answerCorrect"];
    NSLog(@"%@",sImageFile);
```

I have this in my cocos2d Init shown here:

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        NSUserDefaults *sud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *ctlLang = [sud valueForKey:@"ctlLang"];
        NSNumber *questionState = [sud valueForKey:@"questionState"];
        NSNumber *scoreState = [sud valueForKey:@"scoreState"];
        gameArray = (NSMutableArray *)[sud valueForKey:@"gameArray"];
        for (NSString *element in gameArray) {
            NSLog(@"\nQL gameArray value=%d\n", [element intValue]);
        }
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:ctlLang];
        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];

        NSString *sImageFile = [dictionary objectForKey:@"answerCorrect"];
        NSLog(@"%@",sImageFile);
    }
}
```

The printing of the string works fine in the init section of the scene.  The problem occurs in a method I define later.  For some reason it is not returning the string in the method shown here:

```
-(void) checkAnswer: (id) sender {

    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CCMenuItemSprite *sAnswer = (CCMenuItemSprite *)sender;
    NSLog(@"Checking Answer Tag is ---> %d",sAnswer.tag);
    NSString *sImageFile = [dictionary objectForKey:@"answerCorrect"];
    NSLog(@"%@",sImageFile);
    if ([question.answer integerValue] == sAnswer.tag) {
        //...
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?  the program bombs at the NSLog statement.

Comment: By valueForKey, do you mean objectForKey? Anyways, maybe you are not retaining something that you need to?

Comment: Yeah its objectForKey as in the code.  Here is how I define it in the interface:     @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSDictionary *dictionary;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign the object returned by `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` to the `dictionary` ivar but you do not claim ownership of it by sending it a `retain` message to it:

```
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
```

The method `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` returns an object **you do not own**. Probably, by the time `checkAnswer:` is executed the object has already been deallocated. You need to retain it:

```
dictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
```

Or use `alloc-initWithContentsOfFile:` instead, which returns an object **you own**:

```
dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
```

And the same goes for the `gameplay` ivar. You **do not own** the object returned by `valueForKey:` and you need to retain it. So this line:

```
gameArray = (NSMutableArray *)[sud valueForKey:@"gameArray"];
```

should be:

```
gameArray = [[sud valueForKey:@"gameArray"] retain];
```

Comment: Or if the property was not readonly, you could use `self.dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];`.

Comment: @SSteve I did not mention that because the use of property accessors in init and dealloc methods is [discouraged by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I just added a retain to my dictionary statement and it worked.  I thought by defining a retain property in the interface was all I would need, but I understand that the instance var would need a retain as well.

Comment: removing the readonly in the init did not fix the problem.  I tried that before i tried retaining it.

Comment: @Nungster sorry, what do mean by "removing the readonly in the init"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are retaining the autoreleased dictionary created in your init method. You set the dictionary ivar but don't retain it. When you access it later, it is likely not valid anymore